# confirm change SELECT with PHP and JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 files, 1 for the PHP(html) and 1 for the JS code.
I want to confirm any change on my SELECT...

PHP:

```
<select id="transfer_option" onchange="transfer_select()">
foreach (get_users() as $user){
       <option>$user['email']</option>
}
</select>
```

and on my JS file :

```
transfer_select() {
      if(confirm('Are you sure ?')){
            *ajax code, not important*
      }
}
```

But when I change the option and cancel, the option change anyway...

Comment: Did you try the preventDefault function? [Prevent default explaniation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: You should define values in option

Answer (score 0):

Use another jquery library like a sweet alert for confirmation

```
https://sweetalert2.github.io/
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it can be a good solution in the future...
For the moment I want to make functionnal this option